# Aptana Code Format w/ Multi-Line Strings?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, aptana

Is it possible to get Aptana Studio 3 to keep tabs when automatically formatting the code? Right now, it just removes all tabs I have on multi-line strings, and this gets really annoying when working with long queries, et cetera. However, as far as I can tell, there isn't any option for code formatting with strings. Also, I don't want to put additional comments into my code so that Aptana doesn't ruin it--that's sloppy.

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT** - Further testing has confirmed that this only occurs when the PHP is mixed with HTML, and not when the PHP code is standalone.

Comment: You can open a ticket at http://aptana.com/r/apbugs with some code samples and we'll take a look. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise this function work for you, but you can try the menu:

> Mac: Aptana Studio 3 => Preference => Aptana Studio/Editors/Formatter
>
> Windows: Window => Preference => Aptana/Editors/Formatter

There are the settings for format code, select PHP and customize your own.

Comment: I did that, and there's no option for multiline strings.